# Android ListPreference in fragment, how can I make the user-selected choice be run as shell command?

Tags: android, runtime, root, listpreference

I'm trying to add something to /system/build.prop in my app, but I can't figure out how to change it through a ListPreference.

This is how my code now looks:

```
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_monitor);

    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("monitor"));
```

And my XML states:

```
<ListPreference
        android:key="monitor"
        android:id="@+id/monitor"
        android:title="Select monitor"
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:entries="@array/monitor_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/monitor_values"
        android:negativeButtonText="@null"
        android:positiveButtonText="@null" />
```

And Arrays are:

```
<string-array name="monitor_titles">
    <item>320</item>
    <item>280</item>
    <item>260</item>
    <item>240</item>
    <item>200</item>
    <item>180</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="monitor_values">
    <item>320</item>
    <item>280</item>
    <item>260</item>
    <item>240</item>
    <item>200</item>
    <item>180</item>
</string-array>
```

I am able to do this with buttons no problems, adding for example:

```
try{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "su", "-c", "mount -o remount,rw /system" });
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "su", "-c", "sed -i '/ro.sf.lcd_density=*/d' /system/build.prop"});
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "su", "-c", "echo ro.sf.lcd_density=320 >> /system/build.prop"});
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "su", "-c", "sed -i '/ro.sf.lcd_density==320/d' /system/build.prop"});
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "su", "-c", "mount -o remount,ro /system" });
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "su", "-c", "killall zygote"});
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

But how would I go about adding this to a ListPreference? Help would be extremely appreciated!